# How to estimate the value of joint probability density outside the range of variables for which PDF is designed from training data set?

Tags: r, distributions, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I have calculated a joint Probability density function (PDF) for continuous variables using kernel density estimation in R. This data was used as training data to estimate a PDF. Now, my test data has values outside the range of my training data? How do I estimate probability density values for them?

Can extrapolation work here? Or do I need to extend my training data so as to incorporate the entire range? How do I go about that in R?

Answer (score 1):

KDE will assign likelihood values to those test points; if you use an unbounded kernel like the Gaussian, it will even give a nonzero likelihood to all of them, though it will get extremely small for test points beyond a few bandwidths from the nearest training point. This more or less makes sense: the model thinks data very different from anything it's ever seen before is unlikely.

If you're not satisfied with that answer – if you want to get higher values of the likelihood – this becomes a question of changing your model to how you want it to work. One option sometimes taken in one dimension is to [fit Pareto tails](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/paretotails.html) to each extreme. The right thing to use in your case will depend on your  data and what you're using the density estimate for.